# Why do most doors never get closed?

Tags: plot-explanation

In almost every movie or TV episode when a door is opened, the character doesn't bother to shut the door after passing through.  Why?  Would it kill the flow of the story?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19339/49.

Comment: I suspect two reaosns:  It's 3 or 4 extraneous seconds. Why include it?  Also, most sets are not upto Building code, just plywood nailed together. So doors may or may not even function correctly.

Comment: That aside, do you really close every (inside) door behind you?

Comment: @SonnyBurnett I typically close any door I had to open to go through

Comment: If there's a cameraman following the actor, it would certainly present a problem.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Oh man, when I was young I played this game in which you could go into a bank and open a safe using a stethoscope... and it bugged me to no end that there was no way to close the safe or the door when I was done!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Woo - one I know! - often sets are temporary structures and if you slam a door it can make the whole wall wobble (this is often seen in poor-quality shows or ones from the 60's/70's). So many floor managers have just become used to ensuring that they aren't slammed by cast members - even if it's a real set just out of habit. In fact I've seen in scripts lines such as "Door slams [ensure solid door]".

Answer (score 3):

for YEARS i have noticed, and now watching Stranger Things - again, get out of the car, leave the lights on. other times, walk through a door, do not close it... i theorized it is to keep the feeling of continuity going. turning off lights or closing doors [especially when entering, not when exiting like leaving home] would render a change in flow and be distracting. bugged me for years, good to finally Google and research it a bit, and find others noticing the same thing. ah, the beauty of the internet 8).

Comment: It's probably a combination of both of these answers. Turning off the lights and closing the door when leaving a house or office is often saved for significant scenes.